# Visual Studio Data Generation and Many-to-Many

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, data-generation

The data generation tool that comes with Visual Studio allows you to populate tables with random/patterned data.  As an example, you can tell it to populate an Employees table with 50,000 rows and you can tell it to add 5 address rows to an Addresses table for each Employee row.

I've got a junction table much like the permissions example referenced in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table).  Pseudo code below...

```
create table Users (
  UserId int primary key,
  Username varchar(50)
)

create table Permissions (
  PermissionId int primary key,
  Description varchar(50)
)

create table UserPermission (
  UserPermissionId int primary key,
  UserId int, -- foreign key to Users
  PermissionId int -- foreign key to Permissions
)
```

**Is it possible to use Visual Studio's Data Generation tool to populate Users, Permissions, and the associated junction table?**

Using the GUI, I am only able to populate one of the two related tables by selecting it from the Related Table dropdown for the junction table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty good tool that allows you enforce foreign key referencial integrity when populating data. Give the trial a try, maybe it will do what you need...

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-generator/

Comment: Having never found the answer, I will gladly accept yours and award you the necromancer badge. :)